# Switching views using the UIAccelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, accelerometer

Hey guys, Sorry if I'm a newbie on this, I've looked around but haven't quite found out how to do it. Basically I would like to switch views using the iphone's accelerometer. For example, say if the iphone drops, the motion would trigger it to switch to another view telling the user the phone had dropped. Any help on how to do it would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accelerometer can be read using UIAccelerometer class, which calls accelerometer values to its UIAccelerometerDelegate protocol delegate. This means:

h file:

```
@interface TestView: UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
  UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;

@end
```

in your m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
  self.accelerometer.updateInterval = .1;
  self.accelerometer.delegate = self;
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {     
  float aX = ABS(acceleration.x);
  float aY = ABS(acceleration.y);
  float aZ = ABS(acceleration.z);
  if(sqrt(aX*aX+aY*aY+aZ*aZ)>THRESHOLD){
     //Load new view here      
  }
}
```

You can choose THRESHOLD to be anything you want it to be. It implies that the length of the acceleration vector exceeds a certain value. I think this value is usually around 1 if there is no movement, and higher if there is some movement. I would recommend setting this to something like 1.5 maybe? You can try out different values yourself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks helping, the project builds and runs without any problems but crashes when the accelerometer triggers and is about to change the views. Error message I get is: 

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from <FirstViewController: 0x5c42bb0> to <SecondViewController: 0x593d290> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed`

Thanks again,

Comment: I'm not sure if the code I wrote to load the new view is right, maybe this is the problem?

`SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
  [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
  [screen release];`

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. The error you get is because you are trying to launch a transition while the current transition is still running. Don't forget that "accelerometer:didAccelerate" function will get called each time you move your iphone slightly. One solution for this would be to execute the following line right after the if statement: `self.accelerometer.delegate = nil;` This will prevent the function from being called in the future. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, was wondering if you could help me again. Seems by preventing the function from being called has its downside as I can't use the accelerometer again. Basically when I switch to the second view by using the accelerometer and go back to the first view after, the accelerometer function won't work again unless i rebuild the project. Any help on how to fix this please?

Comment: Well, when switching back your views, you have to set the delegate back to self using: `self.accelerometer.delegate = self;`